# RabbitMQ ConfirmListener thread safety

Tags: java, thread-safety, rabbitmq

With RabbitMQ's official java APIs once I have an instance of the `Channel` class I can place it in publisher confirm mode by calling `theChannel.confirmSelect()`. This just places the channel in confirm mode. In order to actually receive confirms it appears I must add an instance of a `ConfirmListener`. This is done by calling `theChannel.addConfirmListener(x)` where `x` is my instance of `ConfirmListener`.

My question is, what thread is my instance of `ConfirmListener` invoked on? I can't seem to figure that out from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ Java client source has spoken: in the same thread that processes the rabbitmq network frame:

See the call hierarchy:

```
ConfirmListener.handleAck(long, boolean)  (com.rabbitmq.client)
  ChannelN.callConfirmListeners(Command, Ack)  (com.rabbitmq.client.impl)
    ChannelN.processAsync(Command)  (com.rabbitmq.client.impl)
       AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQCommand)  (com.rabbitmq.client.impl)
         AMQChannel.handleFrame(Frame)  (com.rabbitmq.client.impl)
           MainLoop in AMQConnection.run()(2 usages)  (com.rabbitmq.client.impl)
```

Comment: Thanks! So this is not a thread from the executor passed to `ConnecitonFactory.newConnection` if I understand the documentation correctly, because they isolated the network connection from the executor. All I am doing is incrementing a semaphore, so I should be safe.

Comment: That's it, executor is used for message delivery / redelivery / consumer cancellation.